# How to get more cursor positions in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cursorPositions = [];

function getCursorPosition(e) {
  let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (cursorPositions.length < 100) {
    cursorPositions.push({
      x: e.clientX - r.left,
      y: e.clientY - r.top
    });
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < cursorPositions.length - 1; i++)
      cursorPositions[i] = cursorPositions[i + 1];
    cursorPositions[99] = {
      x: e.clientX - r.left,
      y: e.clientY - r.top
    };
  }
  console.log(cursorPositions.length);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < cursorPositions.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cursorPositions[i].x, cursorPositions[i].y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

function loop() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  getCursorPosition(e);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

And output:

[image: OUTPUT CANVAS IMAGE]

In this output, I moved the cursor at different speeds and I am getting the dots drawn at distant positions.

I want to get cursor positions more frequently irrespective of cursor speed such that a continuous curve is drawn.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you would do it in the code (you probably know that better) but I would suggest connecting the dots with lines. I know that this would create a slightly bumpy curve with your code as it is now, but it might actually not be too bad. And if you do get an answer that helps you solve your problem, I think it could save you the need for an extremely high dot frequency, reducing lag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a linear interpolation between two of your points.
Say `dl` is the maximum distance between two points

consider `A` and `B`

```
A---x---x---B
```

The goal is to subdivide `[A; B]` such that the x are spaced in a regular fashion but separated by less than `dl`

In function below

```
function interpolate(a, b, dl) {
  const n = d(a,b)/dl
  const nPoints = Math.ceil(n)-1 //1.5 one point middle, 2, one point middle too
  const dx = (b.x - a.x) / (nPoints + 1)
  const dy = (b.y - a.y) / (nPoints + 1)
  const arr = new Array(nPoints)
  for(let i = 1; i <= nPoints; ++i){
    const x = a.x + i*dx
    const y = a.y + i*dy
    arr[i-1] = { x, y }
  }
  return arr
}
```

interpolate does so.

The only touchy part being

```
const nPoints = Math.ceil(n)-1
if n == 1+0.x, we must add only one point between A and B
if n == 2, we must add only one point
if n == 2+0.x, we must add two points
```

The `dx` and `dy` variables simply define the increment over `x` and `y` respectively for the computed `x` points

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cursorPositions = [];

function getCursorPosition(e){
    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(cursorPositions.length < 100){
        cursorPositions.push({
            x: e.clientX - r.left,
            y: e.clientY - r.top
        });
    }else{
        for(let i=0; i<cursorPositions.length-1; i++)
            cursorPositions[i] = cursorPositions[i+1];
        cursorPositions[99] = {
            x: e.clientX - r.left,
            y: e.clientY - r.top
        };
    }
}

function d(a, b){
  return Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x)**2 + (b.y - a.y)**2)
}
function interpolate(a, b, dl) {
  const n = d(a,b)/dl
  const nPoints = Math.ceil(n)-1 //1.5 one point middle, 2, one point middle too
  const dx = (b.x - a.x) / (nPoints + 1)
  const dy = (b.y - a.y) / (nPoints + 1)
  const arr = new Array(nPoints)
  for(let i = 1; i <= nPoints; ++i){
    const x = a.x + i*dx
    const y = a.y + i*dy
    arr[i-1] = { x, y }
  }
  return arr
}
function draw(){
    const dl = 10 // 10px max dist between consecutive points
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(cursorPositions.length == 0) return
    cursorPositions.reduce((last, cur) => {
        const n = d(last, cur)/dl
        if(n > 1){
          ctx.fillStyle = "red";
          interpolate(last, cur, dl).forEach(({ x, y }) => {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();   
          })
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        return cur
    })
}

function loop(){
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    getCursorPosition(e);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

---

As op asked at the very bottom of his post, if wanted behaviour is to get a curve such that curve **is** continuous, a preferable approach to smooth the curve is to take some [bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves).

Below, an application of a cubic one. It is sadly a bit laggy, but hopefully by optimizing a bit **maybe** it could be better

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cursorPositions = [];

function getCursorPosition(e){
    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(cursorPositions.length < 100){
        cursorPositions.push({
            x: e.clientX - r.left,
            y: e.clientY - r.top
        });
    }else{
      //keep the same points for each bezier curve
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.push({
          x: e.clientX - r.left,
          y: e.clientY - r.top
      })
    }
}

function d(a, b){
  return Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x)**2 + (b.y - a.y)**2)
}
function b3([P0, P1, P2, P3]) {
  if(!P0 || !P1 || !P2 || !P3) return []
  function add(...v){
    return v.reduce((acc, P) => {
      acc.x += P.x
      acc.y += P.y
      return acc
    }, { x: 0, y: 0 })
  }
  function s(scale, P){
    return { x: P.x*scale, y: P.y*scale }
  }
  const B = t => add(s((1-t)**3, P0), s(3*t*(1-t)**2, P1), s(3*(1-t)*t**2, P2), s(t**3, P3))
  const nPoints = Math.ceil(d(P0, P1) + d(P1, P2) + d(P2, P3))
  const arr = new Array(nPoints)
  let t = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < nPoints; ++i){
    t += 1/nPoints
    arr[i] = B(t)
  }
  return arr
}
function draw(){
    const dl = 1 // 20px max dist between consecutive points
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(cursorPositions.length == 0) return
    cursorPositions.reduce((last, cur, i) => {
        const n = d(last, cur)/dl
        if (n > 1 && i % 3 == 0) {
          ctx.fillStyle = "red";
          b3(cursorPositions.slice(i, i+4), dl).forEach(({ x, y }) => {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();   
          })
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        return cur
    })
}

function loop(){
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    getCursorPosition(e);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

edit2: lastly one could use the available api [ctx.bezierCurveTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo) which is (unsurprisingly) faster on my machine

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cursorPositions = [];

function getCursorPosition(e){
    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(cursorPositions.length < 100){
        cursorPositions.push({
            x: e.clientX - r.left,
            y: e.clientY - r.top
        });
    }else{
      //keep the same points for each bezier curve
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.shift()
      cursorPositions.push({
          x: e.clientX - r.left,
          y: e.clientY - r.top
      })
    }
}

function d(a, b){
  return Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x)**2 + (b.y - a.y)**2)
}

function draw(){
    const dl = 1 // 20px max dist between consecutive points
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white'
    if(cursorPositions.length == 0) return
    cursorPositions.reduce((last, cur, i) => {
        const n = d(last, cur)/dl
        if (n > 1 && i % 3 == 0) {
          const [P0, P1, P2, P3] = cursorPositions.slice(i, i+4)
          if(!P3) return cur
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(P0.x, P0.y)
          ctx.bezierCurveTo(P1.x, P1.y, P2.x, P2.y, P3.x, P3.y)
          ctx.stroke();   
          ctx.closePath();
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cur.x, cur.y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        return cur
    })
}
function loop(){
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    getCursorPosition(e);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

Comment: OMG!! I wasn't expecting such a detailed answer. Thank you very much!!